# jQuery AJAX request fails in mobile meteor app

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, meteor, mobile

Building my meteor app I noticed that for some reason AJAX requests in the mobile app are not executed at all (I have a form which needs to be ajaxed to external api).

The web app works flawlessly - AJAX request is executed (jQuery $.ajax) but the app build for android fails and does not execute.

The code is plain old jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com:1337/some/url/path',
  data: dataObj,
  success: function () {}
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS